# how to use method result to another method in java

Tags: java

lets say i have a class.

how can i use the result of acceleration method and put it inside the time method?

```
package MyPackage;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MPMethod {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    double distance = 0.0;
    double time = 0.0;
    double acceleration = 0.0;
    double initialVelocity = 0.0;
    double finalVelocity = 0.0;

    public double accel()
    {
        System.out.println("enter acceleration: ");
    acceleration = input.nextDouble();
    return acceleration;                                                                                    
    }
    public double time()
    {
        System.out.println("enter time: ");
    time = input.nextDouble();
    return time;
    }
    public double dist()
    {
        System.out.println("enter distance: ");
    distance = input.nextDouble();
    return distance;
    }


    public double acceleration(double distance, double time) // how can i use the result of this method and put it inside the time method?
    {
      double result = distance / ((initialVelocity * time)+ 0.5 *(time*time));
      return result;
    }

    public double time (double accel, double dist)
    {

        double result = acceleration()*accel *dist; 
        return result;
    }


}
```

Comment: call the method, save the result, use where you want?

Comment: Hint: In `acceleration` you `return result;`. (I really advise you to read a [basic tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/))

Comment: BTW, bad idea to name methods and variables the same, for code readability.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows

```
double accResult=new MPMethod().acceleration(2,5);// will assign 
                                                 the returning value to acResult
```

Now

```
new MPMethod().time(accResult,2);
```